# Load JSON Data onto Bootbox modal

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I am currently working on a project that needs a .JSON data to show up in a Bootbox/Bootstrap modal.

This is what my current HTML looks like:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- dialog body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <!-- dialog buttons -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current JS file:

```
var _modalData = function() {
  $('.item').click(function(e) {

    $('#myModal').on("show", function() {
      $('#myModal button.btn').on("click", function(e) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      });
    });

    $('#myModal').on("hide", function() {
      $('#myModal button.btn').off("click");
    });

    $('#myModal').modal({
      "backdrop"  : "static",
      "keyboard"  : true,
      "show"      : true
    });

    $.each(_itemData, function(idx, it){
      if(currentItemID === it.id){
        var det = '<div><h2 class="Product">' + it.itemName + '</h2><h4 class="Price">' + it.itemPrice + '</h4><p class="Description">' + it.itemDescription + '</p></div><img src="' + it.itemImage + '">';
        $(".modal-body").html(det);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

The modal is working just fine, it's the data itself that is not showing up in modal.

Comment: A few notes - you shouldn't need to remove the click handler from the button when hiding the modal; _itemData and currentItem aren't included in the JS file so it's difficult to tell what their scope is; are there any errors logged to the console?

Comment: var _itemData = {};
var currentItemID = $(this).attr('id'); are what these are in my code sorry I didn't include them. and I don't have any errors

Comment: Do you ever update the value of _itemData?

Comment: No, I have _itemData = data.categories so that it pulls my JSON data

Comment: If _itemData is an object rather than an array then you have your function set up incorrectly. It's hard to help without more information or some example data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this Bootbox, here's a (IMO) simplified version of what you're trying to do:

```
var _modalData = function() {
  $('.item').on('click', function(e) {

    var list = $('<div class="product-list"></div>');

    $.each(_itemData, function(idx, it){
      if(currentItemID === it.id){
        var det = '<div><h2 class="Product">' + it.itemName + '</h2><h4 class="Price">' + it.itemPrice + '</h4><p class="Description">' + it.itemDescription + '</p></div><img src="' + it.itemImage + '">';
        det.appendTo(list);
      }
    });

    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
        title: 'Select Product',
        message: list,
        buttons: {
            addToCart: {
                label: 'Add to Cart',
                className: 'btn-primary',
                callback: function(){
                    // do something here
                }
            }
        }
    });
  })
}
```

This uses Bootbox's [custom dialog](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-custom-dialog) function. You can build up the list of products, and then use that as the message (the content) of the dialog. You'll handle whatever you want your 'ADD TO CART' button to do in the callback of that button; if you don't want the modal to close, add a `return false` as the last line of the callback.

If you go this route, you no longer need the dialog markup you're using right now - Bootbox generates its own.

Comment: Is there a way to get the information of the product in the dialog box. The only thing that is working with the new code is the Select Product. The list is still not showing up.

Comment: @KatieRoberts My answer is based on what your question provides. I can't really answer the question from your comment unless you show what you mean by "not showing up".